# Angular 14 Obtaining values from ngrx store

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm still new to NGRX. I have a home component where I add values into a basketStore :

```
export class HomeMobileComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private store: Store, private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) { }

photos$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectPhotos));
basketPhoto: Array<Photo> = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(invokePhotosAPI());
}

AddToBasket(photo: Photo) {
  this.basketPhoto = [...this.basketPhoto, photo];
  console.log(photo.id);
  this.basketStore.dispatch(basketDetail({ basket: this.basketPhoto }))
}
}
```

this all works fine and I can see my data in the basket using the redux devtools extension.

Now what I'm trying to do is in a header component I'm trying to show the count of items in the basket dynamically.

so now in the constructor of my header I have:

```
basketCount?: Observable<number|undefined>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) {
    this.searchValue = '';
    this.basketCount = this.basketStore.select(basket => basket.basket.length);
    
  }
```

and then on my form I have `{{this.basketCount}}`

on the header it always displays `[Object Object]`

I'm using Angualar 14. Can anybody tell me what it is I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you basketCount is an Observable, you need to read it on your template with the async pipe.

Try `{{this.basketCount| async}}` should work.

Have a look into the docs.
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description